# How to make and fit a thermal model of a house?

Tags: electric-circuits, thermal-conductivity, models

I'm trying to understand in detail the thermal properties of my house. Therefor I'm placing many temperature sensors all over the place and storing all data. In the end I have temp data available from all these sensors at 5 sec intervals.

What I have in mind is to develop an electrical system (with resistors, capacitors and inductors) to model the thermal system of my house (I think temperature in this sense is very similar to voltage(?)). I imagine that between all rooms in my house there are certain of these components (res/cap/ind), that will represent a wall.

Questions are:

1. Does this idea generally make sense?
2. What components should I include between the different rooms? I imagine it's mostly inductors, since only low frequency signals (temperature fluctuations) are passed from room to room.
3. How do I in the end fit all the time series data that I have to the model in order to determined the resistance/inductance/impedance for each component?

Comment: This [page may](https://www.cedengineering.com/userfiles/Cooling%20Load%20Calculations%20and%20Principles%20R1.pdf) give some practical insight.

Comment: @relayman357 thanks that's a very good start indeed!